# Shutting down remote server gets stuck

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have several servers running on Ubuntu 16.04. To shut them down I usually use the terminal of my laptop to connect to them through SSH and then run `sudo poweroff` on them. While this always does the job, it sometimes hangs up the local terminal. I cannot `ctrl + c` out of it. I have to force the terminal to close. I guess my local terminal thinks that it is still connected. This doesn't happen with all my servers though and I can't quite figure out why.

Is this a known problem? Is there a way to not have it hang up the local terminal?

Comment: Try adding an "&" at the end of the command: `sudo poweroff &`

Comment: What about `sudo poweroff ; exit`? That way you immediately exit the `ssh` session after initiating power off.

Comment: Curious if `shutdown -h now` is affected by this.

Comment: I am usually using `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo shutdown -h 0`. Probably `sudo poweroff` is the problem, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [Gilles's answer on related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58355/85039) this tends to occur of the last command doesn't return an exit status, and therefore you may want to run it as compound command:

```
{ sleep 1; poweroff ;}
```

or as subshell

```
( sleep 1; poweroff ;)
```

Consider using alternative solutions also provided on the linked post.